# File shows up in the list of files to commit in GitHub for Windows whereas it is present in .gitignore?

Tags: github, windows-7

I use [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/). How comes `dstc1/dstc_scripts_src/score.csv` shows up in the list of files to commit whereas it is present in `.gitignore`?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the .csv file was accidentally committed to the repo? ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897273/github-for-windows-ignoring-gitignore-file))

Comment: @Dan Thanks, that was the issue. I wasn't aware that the file would be listed in the to-be-committed file list in that case.

Comment: Indeed! I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the .csv was accidentally committed to the repo, so it showed up despite the `.gitignore` rules.

If a file is in the repo then it will show up regardless of what .gitignore says about it -- it's a behavior listed in the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), you can check out the Notes section as well for a few details.

Here's a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897273/github-for-windows-ignoring-gitignore-file/24897907#24897907) with steps on how to get out of it.